# Creating tabel in JSP from an Xml file

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

```xml
<path>
   <path id="Add1">
      <url>http://456</url>
   </path>
   <path id="Add2">
      <url>http://123</url>
   </path>
</path>
```

I have the above XML file and I want to display the ID and URL of the path in the JSP to the User. I have created a Java class which parses the XML and I am retrieving the results. I have to do this using Servlet+JSP where on page load I simply have to display all such tags in the JSP page. There is a text box which filters the results based on the path ID. So I have to send the data back to servlet and get the results.

I'm stuck in displaying the data. How can I display the data of a XML file in a JSP?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `x:parse` and `x:select` from JSTL, it looks applicable.

See also:

- http://www.roseindia.net/jstl/parse-xmlJstlTag.shtml
- http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2003/11/27/jstl2.html

Comment: Hi,I have already written code to parse the XML in Java Class as there's a criteria based upon which i 'm fetching the XML file.That part is already done.All I need to do is to display the values fetched from the XML in the JSP page..and I'm stuck in that.

Comment: @user964819 What kind of help do you need? Where is code for parsing XML? Inside servlet or inside JSP (as scriplets)? I can't see any problem with algorithm: get user input, filter XML based on it, pass result to JSP page and show them to user.

Comment: The code for parsing the XML is in a separate Java class.The whole scenario is I have a text box and I'm getting the user Input as

Comment: The code for parsing the XML is in a separate Java class.The whole scenario is I have a text box and I'm getting the user Input as: <form action="SMSReaderServlet" method="POST">
 <table>  
  <tr>    
    <td><input type="text" name="text" size="50"><br></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Get Data"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr></table>  and passing the user input to a servlet and calling my java class form the servlet & when i'm retrieving the result in the servlet and passing it back to JSP I'm getting the value as null.I'm not able to figure out whats going wrong & where

Comment: @user964819 Read something about servlets first. Write servlet which will get user input and call your class for parsing XML. Than just use `setAttribute()` with `forward()` to pass data to JSP page and show it to user.

Comment: @user964819 please, show me the code (by editing your question).

Comment: can you please share you email id .Its difficult for me to post the complete code here

Comment: @user964819 slava.semushin at gmail.com